# Need Java https proxy which can be enhanced to emulate production https proxy behaviour

Tags: java, proxy, https, debugging

I have a production environment which require access through a proxy server.  Occasionally said server returns blank responses badly confusing the Metro web service library causing all kinds of interesting RuntimeExceptions.  I believe the proxy is Squid.

In order to handle these better, I would like to set up a similar scenario here with a local proxy under my control causing all kinds of interesting failures.  A quick survey strongly indicated I was not asking right.

So, the question is, is there a simple, open source HTTPS/HTTP whatever proxy written in Java suitable for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Apache TCPMon](http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/index.html) could be useful.